# SQLAlchemy recursive many-to-many relation

Tags: sqlalchemy, pylons

I've a case where I'm using one table to store user and group related datas. This column is called profile. So, basically this table is many-to-many table for the cases where one user is belonging in to many groups or there are many users in one group.

I'm a bit confused how it should be described...

Here's a simplified presentation of the class.

[Entity relationship model](http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/7561/profiles.png)

[image: model]

```
user_group_table = Table('user_group', metadata,
Column('user_id', Integer,ForeignKey('profiles.id',
    onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE")),
Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('profiles.id',
    onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"))
)

class Profile(Base)
  __tablename__ = 'profiles'

  id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(Unicode(16), unique=True) # This can be either user- / groupname
  groups = relationship('Profile', secondary=user_group_table, backref = 'users')
  users = relationship('Profile', secondary=user_group_table, backref = 'groups')

#Example of the usage:
user = Profile()
user.name = 'Peter'

salesGroup = Profile()
salesGroup.name = 'Sales'

user.groups.append(salesGroup)

salesGroup.users
>[peter]
```

Comment: Generally, with many-to-many, you want 3 tables -- one for each of the two objects in the comparison, and a third that holds records containing the primary keys of two objects that satisfy the relation.

That said, I'm not sure I understand the question...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I agree with Raven's comment that you should use separate tables for `Users` and `Groups`. The reason being that you might get some inconsistent data where a `User` might have other `Users` as its `users` relations, as well as you might have cycles in the relationship tree.

Having said that, to make the relationship work declare it as following:

```
...
class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'profiles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(16), unique=True) # This can be either user- / groupname
    groups = relationship('Profile', 
                secondary=user_group_table,
                primaryjoin=user_group_table.c.user_id==id,
                secondaryjoin=user_group_table.c.group_id==id,
                backref='users')
...
```

Also see [Specifying Alternate Join Conditions to relationship()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) documentation section.

Comment: Thanks Van


Due the type of the software it's easier for us to store all data in to same table. It's part of the functionality that some users would be acting as a group. 

At first I was also very suspicious of this model, but since it seems to simplify the rest of the software a great deal I've decided to give it a shot.

Comment: Good luck with that. The model might be simple, but you need to ensure the data quality.